# BootStrap having tabs within tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, toggle

I am trying to have tabs within tabs, and I got it to work. The problem is, when I switch from one tab to another, then go back to the tab with the sub tabs, the sub tabs active tab doesn't display what it's supposed to (blank).

Here's the code I used:

```
 <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#red">Red</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#orange">Orange</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#yellow">Yellow</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#green">Green</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#blue">Blue</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="my-tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="tabs2">
                <li class="active">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#red2">Red2</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#orange2">Orange2</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#yellow2">Yellow2</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#green2">Green2</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#blue2">Blue2</a>
                </li>


            </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content" id="my-tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red2">
                            RED 2
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange2">
                            ORANGE 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>

            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>

            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
            <h1>Green</h1>

            <p>green green green green green</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>

            <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little difficult to understand what *exactly* you are trying to accomplish, but I believe this jsbin example implements the behavior you are after.

https://output.jsbin.com/wotowamuri/1

Please note that in the source code you posted in your original question, you have **two** `div` elements with the same `id`.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="my-tab-content">
```

That is bound to cause problems of one sort or another.
In the jsbin example, I have changed the `id` name of the inner `div`.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="my-tab-content-2">
```